# special characters in embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, xhtml

I have some javascript that is embedded in the html file like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            // and the script runs here
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

And it has a line like this

```
if((os == 'Mac')&&((br == 'Safari')||(br == 'Chrome')))
```

Everything goes OK (which means the script works), but [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is screaming:

> ... character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
>   ... This message may appear in several cases:
>   -You tried to include the "<" character in your page: you should escape it as "<"
>   -You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&", which is always safe.
>   -Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a previous tag.

It seems ridiculous to replace all & with &amp. How can I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using XHTML, you need to enclose your inline scripts within a [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Use_of_CDATA_in_program_output):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    document.write("&");
// ]]>
</script>
```

Further reading:

- [About.com: Javascript and XHTML](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm)
- [Codehouse.com: Making JavaScript Compatible with XHTML](http://www.codehouse.com/javascript/tips/xhtml/)
- [Wikipedia: CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

Comment: hell yeah thanks. and it seems funny that i have to escape the `<![CDATA[` thing

Comment: That's because you are trying to write something that is both XHTML and close enough to HTML to work when you tell browsers that it is text/html instead of application/xhtml+xml. It is more effort then it is worth IMO so I stick to writing HTML 4.01.

Comment: ...I still use XHTML, but stick to external scripts for any significant amount of code. Either way, avoid explicit browser-sniffing.

Comment: @bobince: I wouldn't, but the designer made that so I better just leave it alone :)