# Validation Output -> Picking up javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Why is my code picking up the following error?

**Line 32, Column 14: character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data**

```
for(i=0; i <= length; i++) {
```

This message may appear in several cases:

You tried to include the "<" character in your page: you should escape it as "<"
You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&", which is always safe.
Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a previous tag.
 Line 32, Column 14: StartTag: invalid element name

```
for(i=0; i <= length; i++) {
```

**Code:**

```
<script type="javascript">
function randomRange(minVal,maxVal)
        {
        var randVal = minVal+(Math.random()*(maxVal-minVal));
        return (Math.floor(randVal));
        }

        function GetCaptcha() {
        var encStr = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var length = randomRange(4,8);
        var result = "";
        var i = "";
        var char = "";
        for(i=0; i <= length; i++) {
        char = encStr.substr(randomRange(1,encStr.length),1);
        result += char;
        }
        return result;
        }

        function InitCaptcha() {
        var hidFld = document.MyForm.captchaHidFld;
        str = GetCaptcha();
        hidFld.value = str;
        document.getElementById('captchaTxt').innerHTML = str;
        document.getElementById('captchaBtn').value = str;
        }

        function ValidateCaptcha (theForm) {
        var inpStr = (document.MyForm.captchaInpFld.value).toUpperCase();
        var captStr = document.MyForm.captchaHidFld.value;
        if (inpStr.length == captStr.length)
        {
                if (inpStr.match(captStr)) { return true; }
        }
        return false;
        }

        function cmdSubmit(theForm)
        {
        if (!ValidateCaptcha(theForm)) 
        {
        alert ("Please enter valid CAPTCHA Code.");
        return false; 
        }

        if (theForm.name.value == "")
        {
        alert ("Please enter your name.");
        theForm.name.focus();
        return false;
        }
        if (theForm.email.value == "")
        {
        alert ("Please enter your e-mail address.");
        theForm.email.focus();
        return false;
        }
        return true;

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: What `DOCTYPE`, what validator?

Comment: @LinusKleen  W3C and <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: possible duplicate of [special characters in embedded javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302776/special-characters-in-embedded-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that transitional XHTML DOCTYPE you'll need to enclose inline Javascript and CSS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

   /* script here */

//]]>
</script>
```

Compare these results:

- [this is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fperfect-co.de%2Fmisc%2Fso-no_validate.php)
- [this validates](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fperfect-co.de%2Fmisc%2Fso-xhtml_validate.php)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to validate this?  You could always include the javascript as an external javascript file to get around this?
Also: Make sure the script tag is inside a `<head>` or `<body>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. If you bebug the code partially, i.e. GetCaptcha() using firebug, you will be able to track the error quickly. 
or Post the HTML related to this code :)